# Firebase in Chrome extension background script XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm using firebase inside my Chrome extension background script
and as I understood it uses XMLHttpRequest which background scripts are not supporting.

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.24.0): Connection WebChannel transport errored: ...

index.esm.js:943 Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
```

What should I do?

**Update:**
Firebase 9 dont have this problem.

Comment: You can either write a polyfill of it based on `fetch` or don't use firebase in the background script. See also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/xQmZLc8cu6Q/) for more info/workarounds.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have tried to use 'global.XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2')' but now it gives me error window is not defined

Comment: You can try `global.window = global`.

Comment: @wOxxOm same error...

Comment: You need to do it before the imported code runs.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm confused  console.log('global', global); first line in background.js gives error. global is not defined.

Comment: `global` is only defined when you compile the code in webpack or a similar bundler. I thought you knew it since you've mentioned `global`. In case you don't use webpack, use `self.window = self`.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes I use webpack and I noticed that it changes global to window in dist folder. Because of this there was `window is not defined`. I changed it back to global in dist folder. And it started to give error `global is not defined`.

Comment: Well then either find a way to indicate that this entry point is a worker or simply disable `global` in webpack's `node` options and use `globalThis` or `self` everywhere.

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh, I have changed global to self.  And now `self.XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2')`  gives error Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Comment: The xhr2 package you've used is bugged as it relies on the sloppy mode in JS, whereas service worker only supports the strict mode.

Comment: @wOxxOm this problem only gets more complicated. What should I do then I dont know.

Comment: Enjoy ManifestV3, the worst upgrade ever.

Comment: @rendom Firebase 9 still does have this issue for me... Can you elaborate on how you solved it? Thanks